# Pass value from form_tag to controller and then to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, webforms, instance-variables

I've got a generator form_tag where I have checkboxes. I'm not saving these records to the db, but I want to operate on them, so I've got i my 'create' method:

```
...
  def create
    @generator = Generator.new(params[:generator])
    @fname = @generator[:fname]
    redirect_to generators_show_path
...
```

where 'fname' is one of the checkboxes ;)
And I've got in 'show' file:

```
<p>
  <b>Fname:</b>
    <% if @fname.nil? %>
      fname is nil!
    <% else %>
      fname has a value:D
    <% end %>
</p>
```

But every time fname is nil! why?? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you set `@fname` in action `create` and then redirect to action `show` (where the view gets rendered).

When a redirection happens, the current request (existing as an instance of your controller) is finished, and a new request is made - which does not share `@fname` with the previous one.

Therefore, if you want to get the value of @fname right, you should either render the view in action `create` or set `@fname` in action `show`.